# Mousewheel doesn't working (mCustomScrollbar jQuery plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm searching solution for my problem but i can't find it. So I downloaded jQuery plugin (mCustomScrollbar) and everything is fine without one thing - i can't scroll by mousewheel in my test page. Console is clear, examples from author works. I try run my code in latest Firefox and Chrome, but code is not working.

My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="elements">
    <p>Elementy</p>
    <div id="list">
        xxx<br />xxx<br />
        abc<br />def<br />ghi<br />jkl<br />abc<br />def<br />ghi<br />jkl<br />abc<br />def<br />ghi<br />jkl<br />abc<br />def<br />ghi<br />jkl<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#elements').mCustomScrollbar({
        axis:'y',
        theme:'dark',
        mouseWheel:{
            enable:true,
            scrollAmount:5
        }
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
div#elements {
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:350px;
    position:absolute;
    right:10%;
    top:20%;
    width:230px;
    z-index:2;
}
div#elements p {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    cursor:default;
    margin:0;
    padding:8px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

If anyone can help me i will waiting for message.

Comment: I don't have enought points...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, i find solution. So i must using concat version of code.

Then you will use http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js, but not http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js. It's stupid but it works.

Regards

Comment: To handle mousewheel mCustomScrollbar uses jquery.mousewheel.js script that should be included before scrollbar. It is included to concat version, but not to minified one.

Comment: Just as reference, in case someone is using requireJS and is having this issue, refer to [this thread](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/176) on github (you also have to load the jquery.mousewheel.js) - even if your test page (with the same js file and without using require) works fine

Answer (score 0):

try to resolve this problem in webpack, i am comment some lines in mCustomSrollBar.js file.

Problem consist of that file cant find route to node_modules folder for load mousewheel file, so there is a fast solution:

```
function(init){
    var _rjs=typeof define==="function" && define.amd, /* RequireJS */
        _njs=typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports, /* NodeJS */
        _dlp=("https:"==document.location.protocol) ? "https:" : "http:", /* location protocol */
        _url="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js";


    $.event.special.mousewheel || $("head").append(decodeURI("%3Cscript src="+_dlp+"//"+_url+"%3E%3C/script%3E"));

    // if(!_rjs){
        // if(_njs){
        //  require("jquery-mousewheel")($);
        // }else{
        //  /* load jquery-mousewheel plugin (via CDN) if it's not present or not loaded via RequireJS 
        //  (works when mCustomScrollbar fn is called on window load) */

        // }
    // }
    init();
}
```